# MySQL/MariaDB stops running. How do I find out why?

Tags: centos, mysql, logging, mariadb

Today I've seen MySQL/MariaDB stop running on a CentOS VPS. When I check the status I get:

```
# service mysql status
ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists
```

So I remove that file and then restart the service. But then later in the day, MySQL will be offline again and the lock file will be there still. So something is happening that is causing MySQL to die but leave the lock file, which tells me its not a clean/smooth exit.

In the past when I've seen the lock file exist but the service not running it was cause the entire VPS had a sudden reboot. But this isn't the case here because my uptime is 160+ days on the VPS.

I've noticed `fail2ban` banning some random hack attempts on a Wordpress site on the VPS today. So there has been a fair amount of traffic trying to hammer the server here and there until they get autobanned.

1. How can I determine what is causing MySQL to stop randomly?
2. What is the recommended method for auto-restarting MySQL? Can I use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)?

UPDATE: After looking through my `messages` log I'm seeing this:

```
Dec  1 14:06:42 localhost kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 25063 (mysqld) score 24 or sacrifice child
Dec  1 14:06:42 localhost kernel: Killed process 25063, UID 27, (mysqld) total-vm:773716kB, anon-rss:32300kB, file-rss:48kB
```

So this mean that MySQL is simply being overloaded with requests (probably from httpd)?

Comment: In `/var/log` all I see is `mysqld.log.rpmsave`. No other MySQL related logs. How do I enable those?

Comment: How exactly did you install MySQL?

Comment: Correction! Server is running MariaDB. Installed via `yum`. Nothing special.

Comment: OK, then go look at its log files.

Comment: Updated with message from logs.

Comment: I do not recommend supervisor or any other solution uses "autorestarting" services. if it's a virtual machine try to decrease memory usage in your system. mysql stops bc not enough memory/swap available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OOM killer fired as the system was out of RAM and swap - the `mysqld` process was chosen as its victim, likely due to having a combination of high RAM use and relatively low activity on its RAM.

Either adjust the available buffer pool size to make MariaDB take less RAM and not trigger the OOM killer (which might hurt performance) or give the system more RAM or swap.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer led me to this link for more explanation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html Where I found out that (in my case) `httpd invoked oom-killer`